# How can you access via a shortcut the view of a SharePoint site seen when saving a file opened from the site?

Tags: office-integration, save

When saving a document downloaded from a SharePoint site, or opening sometimes a recent file from that location, I get a very nice Open/Save dialogue:

[image: Photo]

But I cannot make this view a Favorite, and when I map SharePoint as a network drive it shows me a simple list of all the folders in the directory, many of which are system folders. I'd like to get a shortcut on the left where users can consistently access the nicer dialogue to open or save files; is this possible?